# What is the difference between Cloud hosting and cPanel hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting, ftp, phpmyadmin

I just want to know whether both of these hosting model provides easy to use interface? Like phpMyAdmin and FTP server to upload file from FileZilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no relation between these two things from which to draw any comparison at all.

Cloud hosting describes a general approach to things at the level of the server architecture, etc.
cPanel is a specific *application* for managing a hosting setup. There's probably nothing stopping a cloud host from offering cPanel, for that matter.

There are a lot of hosts who say they provide "cPanel hosting" but that's not actually a *model* in the way that shared/VPS/cloud, etc. are. It just means they're offering cPanel as their admin area because it's well-known and some people have a preference for it.

If you're looking for a good interface, you need to find out what the specific host is using. Many even have custom admin panels.